# UUIDs: considerations for changing n characters of a version-4 to a word

Tags: partitioning, filesystems, luks, uuid

36 character UUIDs are awesome. But my intuition is that in my personal, home-use, I do not need all the uniqueness that 36 characters provide. But I may not be thinking of all the situations in which they come into play.

I'd like to scrap a few of the characters in a version-4 UUID, replacing them with an something I can understand.  For example, replace 4 characters in the UUID with `cafe`.  This would help me when scripting.  For example, because crypto-LUKS containers do not take labels (that I know of), I'm stuck with dealing with their UUIDs ([unless I write udev rules](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230308))

This increases the risk of collisions. But if my personal sphere for the next 5 years involves 10,000 UUIDs, the risk seems negligible, I think. But I could be wrong.

Anyone with experience with this?

Comment: Formal note: are you talking about canonical 36-character representation? If so, replacing 6 characters with `nights` is impossible because these letters are not hexadecimal digits. You can go with `bad-1dea` though.

Comment: lol, and good point, revised question from `nights` to `cafe`, etc

Answer (score 0):

**Summary:**

Instead of trying to "hack" UUIDs in this way, I suggest that you instead use filesystem labels, partition labels, logical volume names, or script variables, since these tools are all designed for the sort of thing you're suggesting. The details of what would work best depend on your particular needs, which aren't 100% clear from your question.

**Extended recommendation:**

A [universally unique identifier (UUID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) is a 128-bit (16-byte) *number,* typically expressed in a hexadecimal string that, with "-" characters between certain elements, works out to 36 characters. These are not any alphanumeric characters, though; they're hexadecimal numbers. Thus, you can't put in any letters you like, just hexadecimal values. Even aside from the fact that you'd be defying the spirit of UUIDs by doing as you suggest, the limit of using just the first six letters of the Latin alphabet is a big problem with your idea.

Globally unique identifiers (GUIDs) are essentially the same as UUIDs, but different standards use the different names, and there are variants of both. Your reference to `udev` rules makes me think you're using Linux, in which UUIDs are typically assigned to filesystems whereas GUIDs are associated with partitions (when using the GPT partitioning scheme). In Linux, partition GUIDs are often referred to (in `/etc/fstab`, etc.) using the `PARTUUID` identifier.

Both filesystems and GPT partitions can have labels in addition to UUIDs/GUIDs. Because it sounds like you want to make your identifiers intelligible to you as a human, I recommend you use labels instead of UUIDs/GUIDs. In many Linux tools, filesystem labels are referred to using the `LABEL` identifier, and partition labels use the `PARTLABEL` identifier.

It's unclear from your question precisely where you want to use the identifier (you imply in a script, but you don't say what that script does), so I don't know if using either the `LABEL` or the `PARTLABEL` would work for you, but you might want to look into this. Also, I wouldn't rule out writing `udev` rules, if necessary, to get symlinks to devices that use labels; `udev` rules aren't that hard to write, and if they solve your problem, writing such rules would be better than hacking UUID/GUID values in defiance of the relevant standards.

Note, however, that partition labels are a feature of GPT, but not of MBR. Thus, if you're using MBR, partition labels won't be an option. You could switch to GPT (even without re-installing the OS, although you'd need to re-install your boot loader) if this would be helpful, though.

Another possibility might be to reconfigure your system to use LVM. As an example, I use LVM on one of my computers and have encrypted specific LVs within my LVM. In this configuration, an encrypted LV might be `/dev/mapper/myvg-home` and the decrypted version is `/dev/mapper/myvg-home_crypt`. Because LVs are named and are typically referred to in this way, you'll get a more intelligible reference for "free," as it were.

Another option: You refer to scripts. If you're writing scripts that refer to partitions by UUID/GUID values, you could assign those values to variables, as in:

```
HOME_PART="c5424f69-5016-48bd-adf4-76bd95b1f6bc"
```

Syntax details would obviously depend on your scripting language, but that's the core of the idea. You'd then be able to refer to `HOME_PART` elsewhere in the script. If the script was meant to be run on multiple systems, you might be able to find a way to identify specific partitions and map their UUID/GUID values -- say, by parsing `/etc/fstab` to extract the relevant data by mount points. This could be an extremely flexible approach, depending on your specific needs.

Whether you use filesystem labels, partition labels, LV names, or script variables, you'd get the benefit of the (more-or-less) full set of alphanumeric characters, and you would not need to deal with even a partial hexadecimal UUID/GUID value. Some characters might be off limits because of practical limits of the standards in question, but at the very least you could use whatever ASCII numbers and letters you like.